# Toast message not showing and website stuck on refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, toast

I'm using ajax to validate a form and redirect on submission success. Everything is working fine, however on fail where I've set the status code to a specific number to print a toast message, the site would refresh and get stuck, without displaying any toast. 
Everything works fine when I remove the line to display toast.

here is the layout

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="m-0 p-0">
        <div class="alert-container">@include('layout.toast-message')</div>
        {{ $slot}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and in layout.toast-message

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show {{ session()->get('dismiss', '') }}" data-auto-dismiss="2000">
  <i class="fas fa-times-circle toast-icon"></i>
  <div class="toast-message">{{ $errors->has('message') ? $errors->first('message', ':message') : __('The given data was invalid.') }}</div>
  <i class="fal fa-times close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></i>
</div>
@endif
```

This is the toastmessage() function

```
function toastMessage(url, status, message) {
    /* declaring empty data object*/
    var data = {};
    /* adding status property to data with its value of message */
    data[status] = message;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        context: $('.alert-container')
    }).done(function (response) {
        /* alert-container to display response */
        $(this).html(response);
        $(this).show();

    });
}
```

And on ajax fail call where I will call `toastMessage(url, status, message)`

```
.fail(function (jqXHR) { /* on server fail check for json response */

if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
  if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
    /* parse the json response as a message in toastMessage function */
    toastMessage("", 'error', jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
  }
}
});
```

On removing the toastmessage() function, the site refresh and runs fine, so I'm thinking it's something to do with how I've set the parameters that affected the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library, the toast messages created with this library does not block the ui thread.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```

### Visit [this page](https://toastmaker.wirehall.com/) to check more examples with beautiful styled toast messages